# Flutter audioplayers stop playing after multiple play events

Tags: flutter

i'm using this code to play sound whenever I click on a widget.

```
Future<void> playMySound(String who) async{
    AudioPlayer advancedPlayer = new AudioPlayer();
    audioCache = new AudioCache(fixedPlayer: advancedPlayer);
    audioCache.clearCache();
    String localFilePath;
    audioCache.play('roomSounds/$who', mode: PlayerMode.LOW_LATENCY);
    }
```

Problem:
Whenever I tap for example 15 times on a widget that would play the sound, it would stop playing and throw the following stack:

```
E/MediaPlayer( 5793): Error (-38,0)
I/flutter ( 5793): hello 0.0
E/MediaPlayerNative( 5793): error (1, -19)
E/MediaPlayer( 5793): Error (1,-19)
E/MediaPlayerNative( 5793): pause called in state 0, mPlayer(0x77ceaa80)
E/MediaPlayerNative( 5793): error (-38, 0)
E/MediaPlayerNative( 5793): Attempt to perform seekTo in wrong state: mPlayer=0x77ceaa80, mCurrentState=0
E/MediaPlayerNative( 5793): error (-38, 0)
E/MediaPlayer( 5793): Error (-38,0)
E/MediaPlayer( 5793): Error (-38,0)
```

I've tried to use audioCache.clearCache() but with no effect. Only after reloading the application it is possible to play any sound at all.